# Get the indices of a list whose value add up to the given number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values and I input a number. The function has to return the indices in the list whose value add up to the number. The problem is the list contains duplicate numbers and the returned indices should not be the same. Here is what I have but the solution does not look clean. Is there a better way?

```
finalList = []
def getIndices(number):
  values = [10,20,20,50,100,200,200,500,1000,2000,2000,5000]
  for i in range(len(values)):
    if values[i] == number:
      if i not in finalList:
        finalList.append(i)
      else:
        finalList.append(i-1)
      return values
    elif values[i] < number:
      continue
    else:
      number = number - values[i-1]
      if i-1 not in finalList:
        finalList.append(i-1)
      else:
        finalList.append(i-2)
      if number <= 0:
        break
      return getIndices(number)


result = getIndices(450)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[6, 5, 3]
```

If I didnt check the list before appending then I would get `[6, 6, 3]` which is not what I want.

Comment: Cast the list into a `set` first to remove dupes?

Comment: @BAH wouldn't that change the index number?

Comment: @Adib, ah yes, you're right. Then maybe replace all dupes with a `None` or something first.

Comment: I don't understand this part `if value <= 0:` since value is not declared anywhere else. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @Adib corrected it

Comment: There can be multiple answers. Do you want all of them returned? For example if the number is 50 then [0,1,2] and [3] are both valid answers.

Comment: Is the list sorted? If it is sorted you can atleast ignore all values >= to the number, which you can quickly find the index of using bisection.

Comment: @Tommy My solution would return [3] and that is how it should be. Only if you dont find the exact value return the other and the list is sorted

Comment: @KR29 but 10+20+20 is also 50 so I don't understand

Comment: I agree with @Tommy. You'll get multiple answers and there is no one correct answer. Is that the goal?

Comment: @Tommy Am I not ignoring all the values>= number already? The reason I dont want multiple results is because I am feeding the result into another function which I have no control of.

Comment: but @KR29 the problem you identify *has multiple solutions* so *which one do you want*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list of values is sorted, the following code will do what you want. The trick here is to walk the list in reverse order.

**But note the edit and the last test in the function!**

**Edit:** The problem is known as the *subset sum problem* (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)) and is NP-complete. Should have recognized it right away, my bad. This basically means that there is no simple & efficient solution. The simplest solution would be to try all possible combinations, but if your list of values is large, it will simply take too long to complete.

```
def getIndices(number, values):
    '''Return a tuple (n, l) where l is a list of indices in 'values' and the
    following condition holds: n + sum(values[i] for i in l) == number.

    values -- sorted list of numbers
    number -- sum to search for

    >>> values=[10,20,20,50,100,200,200,500,1000,2000,2000,5000]
    >>> getIndices(18000, values)
    (6900, [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
    >>> getIndices(450, values)
    (0, [6, 5, 3])
    >>> getIndices(15, values)
    (5, [0])
    >>> getIndices(10, values)
    (0, [0])
    >>> getIndices(5, values)
    (5, [])
    >>> getIndices(0, values)
    (0, [])

    This simplicist algorithm does not always find a solution with 'n' == 0,
    even if one exists. The following test fails, it returns (10, [2])
    instead.

    >>> getIndices(40, [20, 20, 30])
    (0, [0, 1])

    '''
    n = number
    l = []

    for i in range(len(values) - 1, -1, -1):
        if values[i] <= n:
            l.append(i)
            n -= values[i]

    assert(n + sum(values[i] for i in l) == number)
    return n, l


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: You might as well 'flip' the list

Comment: Of course, if you can keep the list sorted backwards, you can walk the list forward.

Comment: Also, this use case fails on something like n = 0 (even fails at n=10)

Comment: @Markus Thanks that solves the problem. I dont need recursion afterall!

Comment: I think finalList should be defined in the function. Also you can do `return finalList[::-1]` instead

Comment: @StevenSummers I wrote finalList out because of recursion and that got carried over. And I do not care how the order of the indices are as long as they are correct

Comment: I have beautified the function and added documentation and tests. Unfortunately, I found that it does not always find a solution.